# How I can download PDFs of a website by using only the root domain name?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, wget

I am using this command:

```
wget -nd -e robots=off --wait 0.25 -r -A.pdf http://yourWebsite.net/
```

but I can't get PDFs from the website.

For example I have a root domain name:

```
www.example.com
```

and this site have PDFs, DOCs, HTMLs, etc. I want to download all PDFs by inserting only the root domain name, not the exact address of the download page.

Comment: What do you mean "root domain name"There is this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_name_server  but I doubt you mean that. there is this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-1387/ad1intro-41594/index.html but i'm not clear what you mean. Why are you one minute talking about http://yourWebsite.net/  and the next minute talking about www.example.com

Comment: You should clarify the above, but anyhow, You can only get what are linked to. So if there's a webpage that links to the PDFs then you can get them, if not then you can't. But you can get any link on the domain, if there's an html file linking to it that you are reaching.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the provided command to an exemplary website worked out on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine using wget version 1.13.4:

```
$ wget -nd -e robots=off --wait 0.25 -r -A.pdf http://www.cvpapers.com
```

However, it takes some time until the first pdf is downloaded, since the site provides many html-files, which need to be skipped.

Leaving out the "--wait 0.25" option speeds up the process, but obviously increases the workload on the server-side.

If the command does not work for your website, it might be a website-specific problem/layout/..., avoiding a successful download.

Comment: To finally resolve your problem, it might help, posting the specific domain you're interested in.